# How to access elements inside an iframe in ios safari browser when iframe dont have a src URL in it

Tags: ios, selenium, iframe, selenium-webdriver, mobile-safari

I am trying to access the elements inside a iframe on I-OS Safari browser. Its gives me an exception "undefined is not an object " which is logged an exception everywhere in forums.

I got a solution wherein if an iframe has a src URL associated with it the we can do driver.get(the URL in iframe src) and then it allows to access all its elements by find elements. But in mycase the iframe doesn't have a Src URL. Can someone get me a solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
To get object inside Frame, 

driver.switchTo().frame(index);
driver.switchTo().frame("frame name");
driver.switchTo().frame("frame webEleement");
Switching back to the parent window
driver.switchTo().defaultContent(); // coming outside the frame

post html snippet of frame
```

Comment: Hi manjunatha, the above solution doesn't work it gives me same exception "undefined is not an object ". You can go to website m.ebay.com.au and click on sign in tab. Go to register tab. This register section is a iframe i am talking about. Try to access the elements inside register section and do let me know. Thanks in advance.

Comment: try this... WebElement frm = driver.findElement(by.xpath("//iframe[@id='regFrame']"); driver.SwitchTo().frame(frm); driver.findelement(by.id("email")).sendkeys();

Comment: Hi manju, The above wont work. i am able to switch to the frame but not able to access the elements.